# Access TabBarIOS from TabBarIOS.Item?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

My root component of a NavigatortIOS is a TabBarIOS.

When the user is not logged in I'm navigating to the login screen and after login I'm navigating back (using navigator.pop()).

I have several TabBarIOS.Item items and one of them has a logout button which clears the token and should navigate to the login screen once its clicked - but I can't manage to find a way to call a method in the tabs view (parent) from the child (tab.item)...

So I'm looking for a way to communicate between tab items to the parent tab class. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer:

Sending this of the parent (tabs view) using passProps to the TabBarIOS.Item, which is an internal NavigatorIOS - so I can access it form the tab view, who is the component of the internal NavigatorIOS.